# How can I render text from a controller as html on Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I render text from a controller as html?
i.e. `render text: "<html><body>Hello</body></html>", format: :html`

This is being rendered as text. Apparently, this used to work in Rails 3, but is not working anymore in Rails 4.

Comment: Why not regular templates?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
render text: "<html><body>Hello</body></html>".html_safe
```